# Why can't Butterknife find a ViewHolder inside an anonymous class?

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I've got a `ListView` with an anonymous `BaseAdapter`:

```
final ListView myList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_list);
myList.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
```

Inside that anonymous class I have a view holder:

```
class ViewHolder {
    @InjectView(R.id.textField) TextView text;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

        if (text == null) {
            text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textField);
        }
    }
}
```

Setting a breakpoint confirms: Butterknife *always* leaves the `text` field `null`, but directly calling `findViewById` works fine. If I move the `ViewHolder` class out of the anonymous class, making it a member of my main class, Butterknife works fine. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Try to declare ViewHolder as: `static class ViewHolder`

Comment: my hunch is that since it's an anonymous class, ButterKnife doesn't know how to name the generated class, hence it skips it.